# Airdump-ng wlan0mon and does not show any network

Tags: linux, kali-linux, wlan, airmon-ng, airodump-ng

[image]

on my host pc there is showing some wlan networks with my wlan adapter tp-link AC1300. But in kali (my virtual machine) there are no networks at all.

And yes it is in monitor mode and also detected.

[image]

I would like to monitor my own network. But it does not show it. My AP is in my room.
How can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: "on my host pc" does this mean some kind of virtualization is involved somewhere?

Comment: yes i have it edited